# One line HTTP Proxy command?

Tags: command-line, proxy, http, http-proxy

Is there a simple, one-line command to run a HTTP Proxy? There are several one-line commands “serve this directory over HTTP” (e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`). Is there any command, or one-liner, for launching a HTTP Proxy like that? I don't need to configure anything, this is just for short term, temporary use. It doesn't have to be efficient, or multithreaded, or performant. I want something FLOSS, and preferably just an `apt-get install` away on my Ubuntu Linux 18.04 desktop.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412581/seriously-simple-python-http-proxy

Comment: @EduardoTrápani What can be simplier than running one simple command? I'm struggling with it for more than a hour, no one ever thought that I might want to run a simple http proxy that listens one port and redirects to another, without socks, without code?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one - https://github.com/codeallthethingz/single-line-proxy/

Example:

```
npx single-line-proxy "/api/(.*)>3000" "/(.*)>3001" 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt -y install squid && systemctl start squid`

....but the default config on Debian and Ubuntu only permits connections from localhost. so....

`apt -y install squid && echo "http_access allow localnet" >/etc/squid/conf.d/99localnet" && systemctl restart squid`